# URL loop in python

Tags: python, url

I have been working with two APIs to fetch data from amazon.com. Using first API I am getting a series of ASINs (string) and now need to pass first 10 ASINs to second API URL to fetch "Product Description".

I am getting ASINs from first API in below format. All strings

```
B07BJL8CL2
B00CA6X50Y
B01LI4IDQO
B000HTENO8
B00XKXNGT6
```

Second API URL
querystring_lookupProduct = {"url":"https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09BVQPNWZ"}

I have to dynamically replace the end part `B09BVQPNWZ` with ASINs I am getting from first API. Would really appreciate your help.

One is to convert ASIN in list but as I try to do this I get the response like this

```
['B', '0', '7', 'B', 'J', 'L', '8', 'C', 'L', '2']
['B', '0', '0', 'C', 'A', '6', 'X', '5', '0', 'Y']
['B', '0', '0', 'X', 'K', 'X', 'N', 'G', 'T', '6']
['B', '0', '1', 'L', 'I', '4', 'I', 'D', 'Q', 'O']
```

Comment: 1) create a list of strings with ASIN (`asin_to_fetch`), then 2) iterate over this list: `for asin in asin_to_fetch: ...` and 3) use string formatting to build the desired URL: `url="https://www.amazon.com/dp/{}".format(asin)`

Answer (score 1):

```
URL_TEMP = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/{}"

asins = ['B07BJL8CL2', 'B00CA6X50Y', 'B01LI4IDQO', 'B000HTENO8', 'B00XKXNGT6']

for asin in asins:
    url = URL_TEMP.format(asin)
    print(url)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply however when I try to convert the asins in list using asin=list(asin) I am getting it in this format ['B', '0', '7', 'B', 'J', 'L', '8', 'C', 'L', '2'], ['B', '0', '7', 'B', 'J', 'L', '8', 'C', 'L', '2']
['B', '0', '0', 'C', 'A', '6', 'X', '5', '0', 'Y']
['B', '0', '0', 'X', 'K', 'X', 'N', 'G', 'T', '6']
['B', '0', '1', 'L', 'I', '4', 'I', 'D', 'Q', 'O']

Comment: asin is not a string?

Answer (score 0):

```
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/'
Dict = []// create a list to hold the urls


asins = ['B07BJL8CL2', 'B00CA6X50Y', 'B01LI4IDQO', 'B000HTENO8', 'B00XKXNGT6']

// iterate over the asins and populate your list with the values

For asin in asins:
   Dict.append(url + '/' + asin)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply however when I try to convert the asins in list using asin=list(asin) I am getting it in this format ['B', '0', '7', 'B', 'J', 'L', '8', 'C', 'L', '2']

Comment: When asin is a string using the list func will break it down to characters, try changing the " for asin in asins " to " for i < count(asins) " and then using asin[i] as an index